# What happens when you name a Seraph Blade after Raziel?

Tags: shadowhunters

In *The Shadowhunters Codex*, Jace said that you don't name a Seraph Blade after Raziel. Why is that the case? Is it mentioned what would happen otherwise?

Comment: Not having a known answer is not the same as being opinion-based. This has been established policy for a while. I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fairly sure the only canon answer is they do not name blades after Raziel so you can probably have whatever you want happen.

To be fair though since Raziel is the patron of the Shaowhunters something does not necessarily have to happen it could just be considered really bad form kinda like if someone today built a ship and named it the Titanic.